# SQL Parse XML 3rd node data with Dynamic Changing Node Name at 2nd node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I need a SQL Server query that would return two columns with the label of the 2nd node (Such as FirstName) and then the value of the value node under that 2nd node.

For example,
From the XML below, I would need it to return something that looks like this:

| Properties | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| firstname | Tim |
| associatedcompanyid | 328799843 |
| any_challenges_with_it_ | Scanning receipts |
| lastmodifieddate | 1603327685271 |
| email | testemail@gmail.com |
| lastname | Langhard |

```
<root type="object">
    <firstname type="object">
        <value type="string">Tim</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">Tim</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">First Name</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1419225090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </firstname>
    <associatedcompanyid type="object">
        <value type="string">328799843</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">328799843</value>
                <source-type type="string">COMPANIES</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">TestCompay</source-id>
                <source-label type="null"></source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1483733053825</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </associatedcompanyid>
    <any_challenges_with_it_ type="object">
        <value type="string">Scanning receipts </value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">Scanning receipts </value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">Any challenges with it?</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1479235090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </any_challenges_with_it_>
    <lastmodifieddate type="object">
        <value type="string">1603327685271</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">1603327685271</value>
                <source-type type="string">CALCULATED</source-type>
                <source-id type="null"></source-id>
                <source-label type="null"></source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1603327685271</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </lastmodifieddate>
    <email type="object">
        <value type="string">testemail@gmail.com</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">testemail@gmail.com</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">Email</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1479235090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </email>
    <lastname type="object">
        <value type="string">Langhard</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">Langhard</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">Last Name</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1479235090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </lastname>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using a wildcard for a dynamic element name in the `.nodes('/root/*')` XQuery method.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root type="object">
    <firstname type="object">
        <value type="string">Tim</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">Tim</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">First Name</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1419225090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </firstname>
    <associatedcompanyid type="object">
        <value type="string">328799843</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">328799843</value>
                <source-type type="string">COMPANIES</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">TestCompay</source-id>
                <source-label type="null"></source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1483733053825</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </associatedcompanyid>
    <any_challenges_with_it_ type="object">
        <value type="string">Scanning receipts</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">Scanning receipts</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">Any challenges with it?</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1479235090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </any_challenges_with_it_>
    <lastmodifieddate type="object">
        <value type="string">1603327685271</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">1603327685271</value>
                <source-type type="string">CALCULATED</source-type>
                <source-id type="null"></source-id>
                <source-label type="null"></source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1603327685271</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </lastmodifieddate>
    <email type="object">
        <value type="string">testemail@gmail.com</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">testemail@gmail.com</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">Email</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1479235090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </email>
    <lastname type="object">
        <value type="string">Langhard</value>
        <versions type="array">
            <item type="object">
                <value type="string">Langhard</value>
                <source-type type="string">FORM</source-type>
                <source-id type="string">dc18d8a9-7156-4c4d-aba5-f95b3298468d</source-id>
                <source-label type="string">Last Name</source-label>
                <timestamp type="number">1479235090555</timestamp>
                <selected type="boolean">false</selected>
            </item>
        </versions>
    </lastname>
</root>';

SELECT c.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS property
    , c.value('(value/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/*') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+
|        property         |        value        |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| firstname               | Tim                 |
| associatedcompanyid     | 328799843           |
| any_challenges_with_it_ | Scanning receipts   |
| lastmodifieddate        | 1603327685271       |
| email                   | testemail@gmail.com |
| lastname                | Langhard            |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```